# Target unrecognized escape sequence error

Tags: c#, escaping, antlr

I have used AntlrWorks 1.4 before to generate parser and lexer for C# target. Now I am starting a new project and I try to use antlrworks1.5. But the generated lexer has lots of escape sequence error in the C# code. I tried the 1.4 version and it works fine.

Basically, the error is, in the 1.5 generated code, it has invalid escapes like "\1\2\3" while they are "\x01\x02\x03" in the 1.4 generated code.

Is there a way to solve this problem on 1.5 version? Or I have to stick with the 1.4 version.

Comment: You might fire a bug report (issue) https://github.com/antlr/antlrworks, but why do you need to generate lexer and parser in AntlrWorks instead of using the command line tool?

Comment: @LexLi In general, filing a bug at that location is the best bet. This *particular* issue would be closed as "wontfix" (see my answer below for details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# port of ANTLR 3 is not tested to work with ANTLRWorks or when using the Java version of the tool for code generation. It is only tested for using the MSBuild integration and/or Antlr3.exe to generate code. Any behavior that suggests that ANTLRWorks and/or the Java version of the ANTLR Tool can be used to generate code for the CSharp3 or CSharp2 targets is merely coincidental.

You can download the C# port along with documentation for configuring a C# project to build your grammars automatically at the following site:

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3CSharpReleases

Comment: I hope there could be an FAQ somewhere to include information like above for ANTLR C# port, as my project depends on it heavily. But it turns out that I will have to keep a list on my own blog.

Comment: @LexLi I agree it would be nice, but it's really a money limit at this point considering all my work on ANTLR and the C# targets is volunteer time. I'm hoping the documentation for V4 will be better than the current V3 documentation.